# How to Add fraction to a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I added a `ListView` and a `Button` to a layout.

What I want to do is, when I click the button, the `ListView` should scroll to a specified item such as the 10th to the top. But I don't want it to scroll too fast like flipping a page.

How can I do this? Can I add a fraction to a `ListView`? If so, how can this be archived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i haven't try it but you can use "setSmoothScrollingEnabled(boolean smoothScrollingEnabled)" method of listview.

i think this will help you.

Comment: Thank you amit. I'll try this method.